# iphone wifi/3G connection drop problems

Tags: iphone

I know that iPhone shuts down its WiFi connection after 30 mins. Is there any way to keep it alive? How about 3G connection? Does it shuts down its 3G connection after 30 mins? Is there any way to keep the 3G connection alive?

Thanks.

Comment: I think more context is needed to avoid being down-moderated into oblivion -- as written it sounds like a user question.

Comment: Actually I am writing an iPhone application that requires network connectivity. That is why I wanted to know how to handle those scenario.

Comment: I hate it when this happens during an online Texas Hold'em game. :)

Answer (score 1):

Occasionally, even when you're polling something fairly regularly just too keep the connection alive, the iPhone or iPod will feel it's too hot to use the WiFi connection right now. It's probably right, and there's nothing you can do to keep the OS from disconnecting and turning off WiFi, except to pop up a "try again" dialog if you really need a connection for the current operation.

Answer (score 0):

As this posting rates quite high when searching for the WIFI/WLAN iPhone problem - here's the link to the answer: [iPhone SDK Internet connection detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596589/iphone-sdk-internet-connection-detection)