# Internet connection

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone SDK Internet connection detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596589/iphone-sdk-internet-connection-detection)

What is the best way to determine whether there is an available Internet connection for a iphone app. (Programatically of course) I want to disable/hide certain functions if the user is not connected to the Internet.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.........

Comment: Check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596589/iphone-sdk-internet-connection-detection

Comment: Your post title should try and be in the form of a question...

Answer (score 0):

Can you have a look at below post it contains couple of useful post for achieving Reachability code make works.

http://www.iphonekicks.com/tags/Reachability