# Check if iPhone Internet Tethering is Active

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, network-programming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check for an active Internet Connection on iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk)

I am wondering if there is any way to programatically determine whether or not the iphone is actively sharing it's internet connection, either via usb, bluetooth or wifi.

I am making a web interface for my app and would like to know this so i can display the correct ip address.

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: check out this links [link one](http://blog.blackwhale.at/2009/07/check-internet-connection-on-iphone/) [apple example code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) [Previous SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk) [another SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596589/iphone-sdk-internet-connection-detection)