# How to correctly handle unavailability of internet connections in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, cfnetwork

I'm making an app which uses internet. I remember there was something developers had to do with CFNetwork or similar regarding check if availability or speed.

Is there some kind of standard UIAlertView with the message "It seems you have no internet, but you need it for this app"?

Is there a tutorial or guide which show how to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apple provides Reachability class to check for this,

Here is a very simple and effective example.

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/09/14/checking-network-reachability-iphone/

**UPDATE**:

It seems that Apple has updated their reachability class and included the singleton pattern. You can check out the new classes here... http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

thanks @Proud Member for pointing it out.

Comment: It seems this post relies on an outdated version of the Reachability class. There is no +sharedReachability method anymore. They got rid of the singleton pattern.

Comment: yes they have changed from single pattern... I didn't knew that.

Answer (score 0):

see these threads. very Helpfull

[Easiest way to determine whether iPhone internet connection is available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784582/easiest-way-to-determine-whether-iphone-internet-connection-is-available)

[iPhone SDK Internet connection detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596589/iphone-sdk-internet-connection-detection)

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/7300-test-if-internet-connection-available.html

Answer (score 0):

To test and monitor network availability, you should use the **Reachability** class in Apple's sample code - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

There's no standard alert for lack of network availability - how you handle the situation depends on the app you're writing.